# send JSON android object to .net server

Tags: java, android

I have .net web service that expect JSON object. This web service has method for return token:

```
public string GetToken(string username, string password)...
```

This is my site url for direct access (when I field manually id, method and params and paste in browser url I receive response )

```
http://mysite.com/JsonRPC.aspx?id={0}&method={1}&params={2}
```

On stackoverflow I found way to create and send JSON object in android , here is example:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
        JSONStringer json = new JSONStringer()
        .object() 
         .key("username").value("username")
         .key("password").value("password")

        .endObject();

        Log.i("json",json.toString());
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                             entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");//text/plain;charset=UTF-8
                             entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
                             request.setEntity(entity); 
                             // Send request to WCF service 
                             DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                             HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

My problem is that I don't know how to call my .net web service. What format should be URL variable , where to specific method name , and how to specific method parameters ?

Please give me code

Thanks

Comment: You want to know how to make a post request?

Comment: @hwrdprkns I want to call `GetToken` method on .net web service using andorid JSON RPC request.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this library.

http://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/

There are examples on the website that should be sufficient for you.